# SQL alchemy execution error for and_ operator

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, typeerror

I am new to sql alchemy. I have written a SQL alchemy expression in python as follows:

```
s = select([func.count(classifiers.c.comments).label('neg_count')]).where(and_(classifiers.c.comments.like(word),classifiers.c.Tags=='Negative',classifiers.c.company_name==company_name))                    
neg_count_obj = conn.execute(s).fetchone()
```

when i am executing , i am getting an error stating that:

`TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, bytes found.`

Searched it many but cannot find the root cause for this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution which i found out is that in company_name varibale i was getting a ',' which sql_alchemy and_ operator treats as delimiter for conditions. 
Removed that ',' from company_name and found it working properly.